# how to merge 2 pages into 1 in latex

Tags: overleaf, cv, resume, merge

hi i wrote my resume in latex and it suppose to be in 1 page but latex separated my cv into 2 pages
please i would really appreciate if you fixed this while maintain size font to be 11 at least.

thank you and this is the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
% \usepackage[scaled,swashQ]{garamondx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=.9in, right=.9in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

% package settings
\usepackage[
    hidelinks,
    pdfnewwindow=true,
    pdfauthor={Xovee Xu},
    pdftitle={Curriculum Vitae of Xovee Xu},
]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headings}
\markright{\textbf{Xovee Xu}}

\setlength\parindent{2em}

\thispagestyle{empty}

% define cv section
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{\section*{\rmfamily#1}}
\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{\subsection*{\rmfamily\hspace{1.6em}#1}}

% begin
\begin{document}

% name
\begin{center}
    \Huge{
    \rmfamily
    \textbf{Dinah Al-Otaibi}}
\end{center}
\vspace{5pt}


\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

% Contact Information

\noindent Applied Mathematics

\noindent Riyadh, Saudi Arabia

\noindent +966 54 

\noindent ***@outlook.sa



\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}

% Education
\cvsection{EDUCATION}
\indent 
\textbf{Imam Abdulrahman Bin Faisal University}, Dammam.\hfill  05/2020

\hspace{2em}Bachelor of Science in Mathematics (Applied mathematics).  
% academic employment
\cvsection{WORK HISTORY}
\indent

\textbf{General Organization for Social Insurance}, Riyadh.\hfill  01/2023 - Current

\textbf{Food orginazatoin.}, Riyadh.\hfill  11/2022 - 01/2023

\hspace{2em} Business Continuity Specialist (Intern) in Risk and Crisis Management. 
\begin{itemize}
\item Built a Risk Register Dashboard to Track Identified Risks.
\item Worked on Key Risk Indicators.
\item Trained by the Executive Directer of Statistics and Information to Build a Machine Learning Approach to Predict Mortality Status of COVIED-19 Patient.   
\end{itemize}

        
\textbf{JASSER.}, Riyadh.\hfill  10/2022 - 11/2022

\hspace{2em}Data analyst (Intern).

\begin{itemize}
\item Managed the Process of Collecting and Analyzing Graduated Student Data to Calculate Total Addressable Market.  
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Statistics company.}, Riyadh.\hfill  06/2022 - 09/2022

\hspace{2em} Data Quality Assurance in the Census 2022 Project (Temporary Contract)

\textbf{Food orginazation },Riyadh.\hfill  04/2021 - 11/2021

\hspace{2em} Statistical Monitoring Specialist (Intern) in the Scientific Evaluation and Contamination Monitoring Departments.

\begin{itemize}

\item Worked as a Leader on Reviewing the Criteria for Risk Assessment in Feed Project According to FAO Guidelines.
\item Participated in Collecting and Analyzing Data from over 300 Scientific Papers for Contaminant Inventory project

\end{itemize}




\cvsection{COURSES}
\indent

Smart Cities Applications Camps Series: python Fundamentals by Thakaa Center. 

Statistics with SAS by Coursera.

Become a Data Analyst by Microsoft.
\cvsection{SOFT SKILLS}
\doublespacing 

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{singlespace}
\begin{itemize}
\item Teamwork
\item Problem Solving
\item Leadership
\end{itemize}
\end{singlespace}%

\end{minipage}\kern10pt%
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{singlespace*}
\begin{itemize}
\item Critical Thinking
\item Quick and Self Learner
\end{itemize}
\end{singlespace*}
\end{minipage}

%----------------------------------------
\cvsection{TECHNICAL SKILLS}
\doublespacing 

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{singlespace}
\begin{itemize}
\item Excel Microsoft
\item Certified Tableau Desktop specialist
\item Python
\end{itemize}
\end{singlespace}%

\end{minipage}\kern10pt%
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{singlespace*}
\begin{itemize}
\item IBM SPSS Statistics
\item C++
\item MATLAB
\end{itemize}
\end{singlespace*}
\end{minipage}


\cvsubsection{LANGUAGES}
\indent

Arabic

English


\end{document}
```

this is where it got sepreated

[image]

Comment: You need to either cut short your contents or reduce the line spacing. The item sep currently is quite large. // Did you forget `\usepackage{setspace}` so it compiles with error?

Answer (score 2):

The result won't be pretty, but you could use the `savetrees` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
% \usepackage[scaled,swashQ]{garamondx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{savetrees}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage[a4paper,left=.9in, right=.9in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

% package settings
\usepackage[
    hidelinks,
    pdfnewwindow=true,
    pdfauthor={Xovee Xu},
    pdftitle={Curriculum Vitae of Xovee Xu},
]{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headings}
\markright{\textbf{Xovee Xu}}

\setlength\parindent{2em}

\thispagestyle{empty}

% define cv section
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{\section*{\rmfamily#1}}
\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{\subsection*{\rmfamily\hspace{1.6em}#1}}

\usepackage{setspace}


% begin
\begin{document}

% name
\begin{center}
    \Huge{
    \rmfamily
    \textbf{Dinah Al-Otaibi}}
\end{center}
\vspace{5pt}


\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

% Contact Information

\noindent Applied Mathematics

\noindent Riyadh, Saudi Arabia

\noindent +966 54 

\noindent ***@outlook.sa



\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}

% Education
\cvsection{EDUCATION}
\indent 
\textbf{Imam Abdulrahman Bin Faisal University}, Dammam.\hfill  05/2020

\hspace{2em}Bachelor of Science in Mathematics (Applied mathematics).  
% academic employment
\cvsection{WORK HISTORY}
\indent

\textbf{General Organization for Social Insurance}, Riyadh.\hfill  01/2023 - Current

\textbf{Food orginazatoin.}, Riyadh.\hfill  11/2022 - 01/2023

\hspace{2em} Business Continuity Specialist (Intern) in Risk and Crisis Management. 
\begin{itemize}
\item Built a Risk Register Dashboard to Track Identified Risks.
\item Worked on Key Risk Indicators.
\item Trained by the Executive Directer of Statistics and Information to Build a Machine Learning Approach to Predict Mortality Status of COVIED-19 Patient.   
\end{itemize}

        
\textbf{JASSER.}, Riyadh.\hfill  10/2022 - 11/2022

\hspace{2em}Data analyst (Intern).

\begin{itemize}
\item Managed the Process of Collecting and Analyzing Graduated Student Data to Calculate Total Addressable Market.  
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Statistics company.}, Riyadh.\hfill  06/2022 - 09/2022

\hspace{2em} Data Quality Assurance in the Census 2022 Project (Temporary Contract)

\textbf{Food orginazation },Riyadh.\hfill  04/2021 - 11/2021

\hspace{2em} Statistical Monitoring Specialist (Intern) in the Scientific Evaluation and Contamination Monitoring Departments.

\begin{itemize}

\item Worked as a Leader on Reviewing the Criteria for Risk Assessment in Feed Project According to FAO Guidelines.
\item Participated in Collecting and Analyzing Data from over 300 Scientific Papers for Contaminant Inventory project

\end{itemize}




\cvsection{COURSES}
\indent

Smart Cities Applications Camps Series: python Fundamentals by Thakaa Center. 

Statistics with SAS by Coursera.

Become a Data Analyst by Microsoft.
\cvsection{SOFT SKILLS}
%\doublespacing 

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{singlespace}
\begin{itemize}
\item Teamwork
\item Problem Solving
\item Leadership
\end{itemize}
\end{singlespace}%

\end{minipage}\kern10pt%
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{singlespace*}
\begin{itemize}
\item Critical Thinking
\item Quick and Self Learner
\end{itemize}
\end{singlespace*}
\end{minipage}

%----------------------------------------
\cvsection{TECHNICAL SKILLS}
%\doublespacing 

\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{singlespace}
\begin{itemize}
\item Excel Microsoft
\item Certified Tableau Desktop specialist
\item Python
\end{itemize}
\end{singlespace}%

\end{minipage}\kern10pt%
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\begin{singlespace*}
\begin{itemize}
\item IBM SPSS Statistics
\item C++
\item MATLAB
\end{itemize}
\end{singlespace*}
\end{minipage}


\cvsubsection{LANGUAGES}
\indent

Arabic

English


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the font sizes for the header and the sectional titles, suppress most of the vertical spaces (boldface is already sufficient to navigate the document). Reduce also the margins.

I also used `multicol` for the last two lists.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[small]{titlesec}

% package settings
\usepackage[
    hidelinks,
    pdfnewwindow=true,
    pdfauthor={Xovee Xu},
    pdftitle={Curriculum Vitae of Xovee Xu},
]{hyperref}

%\pagestyle{headings}
%\markright{\textbf{Xovee Xu}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,leftmargin=10pt}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}

\thispagestyle{empty}

% define cv section
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{\section*{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{\subsection*{\hspace{1.6em}#1}}

% begin
\begin{document}

% name
\begin{center}\huge\bfseries
Dinah Al-Otaibi
\end{center}


% Contact Information

Applied Mathematics

Riyadh, Saudi Arabia

+966 54 

***@outlook.sa



% Education
\cvsection{EDUCATION}
\indent 
\textbf{Imam Abdulrahman Bin Faisal University}, Dammam.\hfill  05/2020

\hspace{2em}Bachelor of Science in Mathematics (Applied mathematics).  

% academic employment
\cvsection{WORK HISTORY}

\textbf{General Organization for Social Insurance}, Riyadh.\hfill  01/2023 - Current

\textbf{Food orginazatoin.}, Riyadh.\hfill  11/2022 - 01/2023

\hspace{2em} Business Continuity Specialist (Intern) in Risk and Crisis Management. 
\begin{itemize}
\item Built a Risk Register Dashboard to Track Identified Risks.
\item Worked on Key Risk Indicators.
\item Trained by the Executive Directer of Statistics and Information to Build a Machine Learning Approach to Predict Mortality Status of COVIED-19 Patient.   
\end{itemize}

        
\textbf{JASSER.}, Riyadh.\hfill  10/2022 - 11/2022

\hspace{2em}Data analyst (Intern).

\begin{itemize}
\item Managed the Process of Collecting and Analyzing Graduated Student Data to Calculate Total Addressable Market.  
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Statistics company.}, Riyadh.\hfill  06/2022 - 09/2022

\hspace{2em} Data Quality Assurance in the Census 2022 Project (Temporary Contract)

\textbf{Food orginazation },Riyadh.\hfill  04/2021 - 11/2021

\hspace{2em} Statistical Monitoring Specialist (Intern) in the Scientific Evaluation and Contamination Monitoring Departments.

\begin{itemize}

\item Worked as a Leader on Reviewing the Criteria for Risk Assessment in Feed Project According to FAO Guidelines.
\item Participated in Collecting and Analyzing Data from over 300 Scientific Papers for Contaminant Inventory project

\end{itemize}


\cvsection{COURSES}

Smart Cities Applications Camps Series: python Fundamentals by Thakaa Center. 

Statistics with SAS by Coursera.

Become a Data Analyst by Microsoft.


\begin{multicols}{2}[\cvsection{SOFT SKILLS}]
\begin{itemize}
\item Teamwork
\item Problem Solving
\item Leadership
\item Critical Thinking
\item Quick and Self Learner
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

%----------------------------------------

\begin{multicols}{2}[\cvsection{TECHNICAL SKILLS}]
\begin{itemize}
\item Excel Microsoft
\item Certified Tableau Desktop specialist
\item Python
\item IBM SPSS Statistics
\item C++
\item MATLAB
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}


\cvsubsection{LANGUAGES}

Arabic

English

\end{document}
```

[image]